# How to make a loop that changes values in specific rows from a dictionary

Tags: r, dplyr, nested-loops, data-manipulation, stringr

I'm new and can't figure it out how to solve this problem.
I have a data.frame = schedule

| Week_number | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 09:00 | 15:00 |
| 1 | 09:00 | 15:00 |
| 1 | 09:00 | 15:00 |
| 1 | 09:00 | 15:00 |
| 1 | 09:00 | 15:00 |
| 1 | NA | NA |
| 1 | NA | NA |
| 2 | 09:00 | 15:00 |
| 2 | 09:00 | 15:00 |
| 2 | 09:00 | 15:00 |
| 2 | 09:00 | 15:00 |
| 2 | 09:00 | 15:00 |
| 2 | NA | NA |
| 2 | NA | NA |
| 3 | 09:00 | 15:00 |
| 3 | 09:00 | 15:00 |
| 3 | 09:00 | 15:00 |
| 3 | 09:00 | 15:00 |
| 3 | 09:00 | 15:00 |
| 3 | NA | NA |
| 3 | NA | NA |
| ----------------------------- |  |  |
| .. |  |  |
| 52 |  |  |
| ----------------------------- |  |  |

I have a shift dictionary :

```
> start_vec <- c("06:00", "08:00", "14:00")
> end_vec <- c("14:00", "16:00", "22:00")
```

My loop is to go through all 52 weeks and replace 9am and 3pm with a dictionary value.
But the problem is that the values should not be repeated, i.e. each week should be different.

For example, I start the year with : 08:00 - 16:00. The year can start with any shift.
Please find an example below :

| Week_number | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 08:00 | 16:00 |
| 1 | 08:00 | 16:00 |
| 1 | 08:00 | 16:00 |
| 1 | 08:00 | 16:00 |
| 1 | 08:00 | 16:00 |
| 1 | NA | NA |
| 1 | NA | NA |
| 2 | 14:00 | 22:00 |
| 2 | 14:00 | 22:00 |
| 2 | 14:00 | 22:00 |
| 2 | 14:00 | 22:00 |
| 2 | 14:00 | 22:00 |
| 2 | NA | NA |
| 2 | NA | NA |
| 3 | 06:00 | 14:00 |
| 3 | 06:00 | 14:00 |
| 3 | 06:00 | 14:00 |
| 3 | 06:00 | 14:00 |
| 3 | 06:00 | 14:00 |
| 3 | NA | NA |
| 3 | NA | NA |
| ----------------------------- |  |  |
| .. |  |  |
| 52 |  |  |
| ----------------------------- |  |  |

I tryed to make nest loop, or make week_number vector to be able replace all 1 without NA with specific value.

```
> rd_dt <- data.frame()
> for (i in 1:length(schedule$Week_number)){
> for (s in start_vec){
> for (e in end_vec){
> dt <- schedule[i,] 
> if (schedule$Start == NA){
> next
> else {
```

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: From you description I don't understand according to which logic the values should be replaced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not need a loop to do this. Here is one approach that may be helpful. Using `ifelse` check for `NA` - if *not* `NA`, then refer to `start_vec` and `end_vec` for substitute values. It will use the `Week_number` as an index in your vector, and uses the `%%` modulus operator where 3 is the length of your vectors, so it will restart at beginning if exceeds the length of the vectors.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Start = ifelse(is.na(Start), NA, start_vec[1 + Week_number %% 3]),
         End = ifelse(is.na(End), NA, end_vec[1 + Week_number %% 3]))
```

**Output**

```
   Week_number Start   End
1            1 08:00 16:00
2            1 08:00 16:00
3            1 08:00 16:00
4            1 08:00 16:00
5            1 08:00 16:00
6            1  <NA>  <NA>
7            1  <NA>  <NA>
8            2 14:00 22:00
9            2 14:00 22:00
10           2 14:00 22:00
11           2 14:00 22:00
12           2 14:00 22:00
13           2  <NA>  <NA>
14           2  <NA>  <NA>
15           3 06:00 14:00
16           3 06:00 14:00
17           3 06:00 14:00
18           3 06:00 14:00
19           3 06:00 14:00
20           3  <NA>  <NA>
21           3  <NA>  <NA>
```